# What is the difference between these two methods of writing files

Tags: python, writefile

I use the following two methods to write a txt file, and I got different results.

First method:

```
with open("raw_train.txt", "a") as f0:
    for sent in reader_train.sents():
        f0.write(' '.join(sent))
        f0.write('\n')
```

Second method:

```
f1 = open("raw_train.txt", "a")
for sent in reader_train.sents():
    f1.write(' '.join(sent))
    f1.write('\n')
```

The `reader_train.sents()` is a list of length 39832. Method1 gave me the correct output, but the output of method2 has only 39812 lines with the last 20 entries of the original list removed. I cannot understand the difference between these two methods.

Comment: Are you sure `reader_train.sents()` gives the same result in the two codes? Maybe you should try replacing it with something consistent and try again.

Comment: `with open("raw_train.txt", "a") as f0:` closes the file handle after writing the file as it goes out of scope in example 1, in the second example you have to manually close the file or you will get OSError.

Comment: Thank you @KunalMukherjee, after I close the file I got the correct result.

Comment: Yes, it is a consistent list. I think the problem lies in closing the file as Kunal mentioned. @iBug

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the second method, you should also close the file once you're done writing to it. This is to ensure that the data that was still in the buffer is properly flushed to the file.

```
f1 = open("raw_train.txt", "a")
for sent in reader_train.sents():
    f1.write(' '.join(sent))
    f1.write('\n')
f1.close()
```

The 'with' statement takes care of closing the file automatically once the operation is done, so you don't have to do it manually, which is why it works correctly for your first method

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Should I close the file every iterations? I mean whether the f1.close() should be outside of the for loop?

Comment: @luw yeah my bad, it should be outside